# NestJS not getting file data from angular

Tags: angular, file, upload, nestjs, backend

So, when i make a request to the api to upload a file, then the file is undefined, but in angular its not undefined

Heres my code:

**Angular HTML**

```
          <label *ngIf="newPfpPreviewSRC == ''" for="newpfpinput">{{'selectpic'|translate}}</label>
          <input #newPFP (change)="getPfpPreview($event)" type="file" id="newpfpinput" hidden /><br />
<button (click)="pfpYES()" mat-raised-button>{{'yes'|translate}}</button>
```

**Angular component.ts**

```
  newPfpPreviewSRC: any = '';
  pfpData: any = '';
  getPfpPreview(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];

      this.pfpData = event.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => (this.newPfpPreviewSRC = reader.result);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
  async pfpYES() {
    console.log(this.pfpData)
    this.http
      .post(`http://localhost:3000/api/user/newpfp`, {
        userid: this.userid,
        pfp: await this.pfpData
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

**NestJS**

```
    @Post("newpfp")
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    newPfp(@Body() uploadpfpdto: UploadPFPDto){
        console.log(uploadpfpdto)
    }
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: what do you see from network panel when you debug?

Comment: on the backend its undefined. On the frontend its working